# Problema al hacer fetch con Pinia y Nuxtjs 3

Tags: nuxt, pinia

Actualmente tengo una app que ya tiene un login implementado y guarda en las cookies el token para realizar luego mas peticiones a mi API.

La idea es que al navegar a la pagina de clientes, la app sea capaz de hacer la petición a la API y extraer toda la información de los clientes y mostrarlos en la pagina.

Hasta ahora no funciona de esa forma, sino que al navegar a la pagina /clients se carga la pagina sin la información y para poder verla necesito recargar la pagina. Soy algo nuevo con Nuxtjs 3 y aun no entiendo bien que error tengo en mi código.

Este es mi ClientStore:

```
import { defineStore } from 'pinia';
import clientApi from '../api/client';

type Client = {
    first_name: string;
    last_name: string;
    email: string;
    phone: string;
    celphone: string;
    address: string;
};


export const useClientsStore = defineStore('clients', {
    state: () => ({
        clients: [],
        loading: false
    }),

    actions: {
        async fetchClients(limit: number, page: number, token: string) {
            try {
                this.loading = true;
                const response = await clientApi.getClientsPaginated(limit, page, token);
                this.clients = response.data;
                this.loading = false;

            } catch (error) {
                console.error('Error al obtener los clientes:', error);
                this.loading = false;
                throw error;
            }
        },
    },

    getters: {
        totalClients: (state) => state.clients?.length,
        getClients: (state) => state.clients,
    }

});
```

Y esta es mi pagina de clientes:

```
 <template>
      <div>
        <h1>Clients Page</h1>
        <div v-if="loading">Loading...</div>
        <div v-else>
          <div v-if="totalClients === 0">No clients found.</div>
          <ul v-else>
            <li v-for="client in clients" :key="client.email">
              <p>Name: {{ client.first_name }} {{ client.last_name }}</p>
              <p>Email: {{ client.email }}</p>
              <p>Phone: {{ client.phone }}</p>
              <p>Celphone: {{ client.celphone }}</p>
              <p>Address: {{ client.address }}</p>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
    
        <button @click="toggleModal">Add New Client</button>
        <BaseModal v-if="modalActive" @close="toggleModal">
          <form @submit.prevent="handleSaveClient">
            <label for="first_name">First Name:</label>
            <input v-model="first_name" type="text" id="first_name" required>
            <!-- Other input fields for last_name, email, phone, celphone, and address -->
    
            <button type="submit">Save</button>
          </form>
        </BaseModal>
      </div>
    </template>
    
    <script setup>
    import Icon from "../components/base/LucideIcon.vue";
    import BaseModal from "../components/base/BaseModal.vue";
    import { useAuthStore, useClientsStore } from "../stores";
    import { storeToRefs } from "pinia";
    
    const clientStore = useClientsStore();
    const authStore = useAuthStore();
    const { user } = authStore;
    let modalActive = ref(null);
    const { clients, loading, fetchClients, totalClients } = clientStore;
    
    // Form
    const first_name = ref("");
    const last_name = ref("");
    const email = ref("");
    const phone = ref("");
    const celphone = ref("");
    const address = ref("");
    
    const toggleModal = () => {
      modalActive.value = !modalActive.value;
    };
    
    onMounted(async () => {
      try {
        const data = await fetchClients(10, 0, user.token);
        console.log("data", data);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error fetching clients:", error);
      }
    });
    
    const data = await clientStore.fetchClients(10, 0, authStore.user.token);
    
    const handleSaveClient = async () => {
      const { error } = auth.login(router, email.value, password.value);
      if (error) console.log(error);
    };
    </script>
    
    <style lang="scss" scoped></style>
```